# Record video from webcam in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Is there a way to record a video from the webcam in Angular, using ngx-webcam ?
If not,  do you know any technology that is compatible with Angular/TypeScript, that could allow me to show a webcam preview on my web app and then start recording the video output once a record button is pressed ?
Thank you!